# flutter package:flutter_app_badger is not working in android and status is platform supported

Tags: flutter

I want to use flutter app badge for incoming notification, I used package **"package:flutter_app_badger"** but its not working. Its not giving me error message also and it run succefully but its not working.

I am using android vivo mobile for testing.

When i check this package is supported to my device or not ? with following code and its says yes, this device is supported app badger.

for platform checking:

```
FlutterAppBadger.isAppBadgeSupported();
```

for add badge on app icon i below code simply:

```
FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);
```

can anyone please solve this query its really helpful to me.